# jQuery Delegation Coding Not Working

Tags: jquery, delegation

I have this snippet of code and the Ajax call works grand and displays grand, my issue is how can I get vote click to work with the data loaded via the ajax call into `#existingComments` as the ajax call is firing on page load?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var vData = {aid:2,rid:2};

    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : vData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            $("#existingComments").html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            $("#existingComments").html("");
        }
    });

    // Disable links on vote buttons
    $(".vote").on("click", "a", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('yup');
    });
});
</script>
```

Code snippet of whats loaded into `#existingComments`:

```
<div class="comment">
    <div data-cid="1" class="vote">
        <a title="+1 Vote" href="#"><span class="upVote">&nbsp;</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are you calling commentVote?

Comment: commentVote is generated and loaded into `#existingComments` as the AJAX call fires on page load. I'm trying to use a function as the code needs to be called from a second place outside this AJAX call.

Comment: Oh yes but the function  itself is called ?

Comment: Ah I see your point, say I took the code snippet out of the function, where would it need to be put to effect the AJAX loaded code?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML markup and the HTML being returned in the AJAX response. There's not enough information here.

Comment: @nderscore, sorry, I've added an example of the code snippet loaded via the AJAX call.

Comment: And yes you can attach it also to the div ...

Comment: @darkajax, I tried the first answer but it didn't seem to work but the second answer worked first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding your delegated event to a dynamic element that does not exist until after your AJAX response comes back. You should bind your event to the container div instead.

Here's an example:

```
$("#existingComments").on("click", ".vote a", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('yup');
 });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/75/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".vote a", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('yup');
        });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMHsJ/)